# Get the 50th and 100th sale of a user

Tags: sql, mariadb

There are many products in the database table. I want to create report that shows the 10th and 25th.. etc order of that product and log who bought it.

currently I have

```
select 
    CONCAT(sales.lastName,' / ', sales.firstName) as salesNames,
    sales.created_at as Sale_Date

FROM Sales
JOIN users ON sales.user_id = users.id
WHERE sales.status = 1
AND sales.created_at < CURDATE()
```

If someone can lead me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Basically my end result would be like

```
sale_day.  salesNames
10.        John/Joe
10         Smith/Ralley
10         Gruni/Mark
25.        Tony Rick
25         Brunel Brada
25         Mary Lofe
```

Comment: What version of MySQL? If there is no "sale counter" column that is incremented for each user, then we'd need to calculate it, label rows as 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. for each sale. The `ROW_NUMBER()` window function was introduced (finally!) in MySQL 8.0. For earlier versions, we could make use of MySQL user-defined variables to calculate the row number, in carefully crafted queries.

Comment: Is it MySQL or MariaDB? Those two are becoming quite different nowadays.

Comment: @TheImpaler This is MariaDB

Comment: Which MariaDB version? 10.2, newer, older?

Comment: Mariadb version 10.2

Comment: Search for window function Partition by clause.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` can be simulated using @variables.

Answer (score 0):

In MariaDB 10.2, you can  use `row_number()`.  Your explanation is not clear -- why is the `users` table being joined in?  What is the product?

But I think you are looking for something like:

```
select concat(u.lastName, ' / ', u.firstName) as salesNames,
       s.created_at as Sale_Date
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by s.product_id order by s.created_at) as seqnum
      from sales s
      where s.status = 1 and
            s.created_at < CURDATE()
     ) s join
     users u
     on s.user_id = u.id
where seqnum in (10, 25);
```